# previous/next_post_link in the same sub-category?

Tags: categories, navigation, single, next-post-link, previous-post-link

As the title: is there a way to navigate between posts of the same subcategory using the `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` functions? But maintaining however both the category and the sub-category of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ll take a look at [`next_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) Codex page, you’ll see it’s usage:

```
<?php
next_post_link(
    $format,
    $link,
    $in_same_term   = false,
    $excluded_terms = '',
    $taxonomy       = 'category'
);
```

As you can see, third param is `in_same_term` and it’s default value is false. If you set it to true, then the function will return next post from same category. (If you want the term from different taxonomy, you can change fifth param).

So answering your question... Yes, there is a way to achieve this. It can look like so:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link &raquo;', '%title', true ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for replay i'm using this parameter
( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentytwelve', true), but it does not work I get the previous link in the parent category

category/subcategory/post-n3    the p-link instead of going to:
category/subcategory/post-n2     go to:
category/post-n1

Comment: But you do you pass 'twentytwelve' as third param?

Comment: it has remained from the used snippets but this is not the problem, I have just tested it as a third parameter

( '&larr;', 'Previous post link',  true)

Comment: You can’t set random values for params and expect them to work... third param should be true... not some random string. And it will work only if the given post has only one term in given taxonomy (otherwise it will take first of terms, AFAIR)

Comment: the thing has never given problems for the posts in the same category in tot developed themes, while it does not work for the subcategorie as it does not work with true as the third parameter..

Comment: ok, so $in_same_term true it works only by deleting the parent category from the post, better than nothing, but the goal is to find the way to keep navigation in the two levels: both for categories and for sub-categories

Comment: For example: I would like to be able to chronologically browse all works in the works category (works/workfoclient1> works/workfoclient2> works/workfoclient3> works/otherworkfoclient1) but I would also like to browse for jobs in the client subcategory1 (works/ client1/ workfoclient1> works/client1/otherworkfoclient1)

Comment: @claudio you won’t find such a way. If you are in single post, you don’t know from which category have you come. So...

Comment: I guess it's complicated but not impossible because the browser and the server know where we are, for example the information we can take from the path of the URL, I think I would need a greater mastery of php and for this I am here: ) Thanks again

Comment: @claudio but you don’t have that information on server-side. On the other hand you can use multiple tabs (so you go to the site without context/history) and so on...